# Is there a tool that checks for cheats and hacks in a given replay?

Tags: starcraft-2, cheats

Starcraft and Warcraft 3 had both sophisticated tools to check if someone cheated during a game (BWChart and W3Chart). They checked for strange behavior and impossible clicks, like selecting opponents units which are disguised by fog of war.

Does such a tool exist for Starcraft 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SC2Gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/features) is your best bet. I don't know if it's capable of checking for out-of-vision selections at this time, but if not you can suggest it to the creator who's pretty active in updating it.